Android Build Error with Geolocator Package: "Cannot Find Symbol: LocationRequest.Builder"
I'm using the geolocator: ^13.0.1 package in my Flutter app, and I'm encountering a build error specifically on Android. The error message is as follows:
error: cannot find symbol
    LocationRequest.Builder builder = new LocationRequest.Builder(0);
                   ^
  symbol:   class Builder
  location: class LocationRequest

I have tried flutter clean, flutter pub cache repair, remove the ./gradle, nothing work.
I have got my dependencies set to compileSdkVersion 34, same problem persist. Has anyone else encountered this issue, and how can I resolve it? Is it related to changes in the Android API or compatibility with the geolocator package version I'm using? Any help would be appreciated!
